# Fading in/Fade out text in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, fade

I had a problem and whipped up a quick solution: fade-in and fade-out a series of quotations. My solution works just as I want it in every browser except any of the IEs. The only problem with the IEs is that the text does not fade in and fade out; the text simply pops into existence.

I believe I've run into a similar problem before when trying to dynamically change the `filter:alpha(opacity=xx)` of an element.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.fadetext{
background:green;
border:1px solid red;
height:50px;
width:500px;
}

.fadetext div{
background:yellow;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var CI_common = {
    C:function(cls,elm){
        if(!elm) elm = document;
        if(document.getElementsByClassName){
            return elm.getElementsByClassName(cls);
        }else{
            var t = [];
            var o = elm.getElementsByTagName("*");
            var r = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + cls + "($|\\s)");
            for(var i=0;i<o.length;i++){
                if(o[i].className.match(r)) t.push(o[i]);
            }
            return t;
        }
    },

    eventAdd:function(obj,evt,func){
        if(obj.addEventListener){
            obj.addEventListener(evt,func,false);
        }else if(obj.attachEvent){
            obj["x" + evt + func] = func;
            obj[evt + func] = function(){
                obj["x" + evt + func](window.event);
            }
            obj.attachEvent("on" + evt,obj[evt + func]);
        }
    }
}

var CI_fadetext = {
    init:function(){
        var c = CI_common.C("fadetext"); // Simply a getElementsByClassName function
        for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){
            c[i].style.overflow = "hidden";
            var kids = c[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var j=0;j<kids.length;j++){
                kids[j].style.display = "none";
                kids[j].style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
                kids[j].style.opacity = "0";
                (function(obj,index,len){
                    obj.fadetexttimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                        CI_fadetext.fade(obj,true);
                        obj.fadeininterval = setInterval(function(){
                            CI_fadetext.fade(obj,true);
                        },5000*len)
                    },5000*index);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        CI_fadetext.fade(obj,false);
                        obj.fadeoutinterval = setInterval(function(){
                            CI_fadetext.fade(obj,false);
                        },5000*len)
                    },5000*index+4400);
                })(kids[j],j,kids.length);
            }
        }
    },

    fade:function(elm,dir){
        function fade(start){
            start = (dir ? start + 10 : start - 10);
            elm.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + start + ")";
            elm.style.opacity = start/100;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = elm.style.filter;
            if(start > 100 || start <0){
                elm.style.display = (dir ? "" : "none");
                elm.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (dir ? 100 : 0) + ")";
                elm.style.opacity = (dir ? 1 : 0);
            }else elm.fadetexttimeout = setTimeout(function(){fade(start);},50);

        }
        if(dir){
            elm.style.display = "";
            fade(0);
        }else fade(100);
    }
}

CI_common.eventAdd(window,"load",CI_fadetext.init); // Just a window.onload level 2 event listener
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
<div class="fadetext">
    <div>AAAA</div>
    <div>BBBB</div>
    <div>CCCC</div>
    <div>DDDD</div>
    <div>EEEE</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value to the filter array rather than the style element.  Then IE be able to keep up.

```
if (elm.filters)
elm.filters[0].opacity=value
```

Comment: P.S. There's also a quirk in IE6 that may bite you.  It doesn't like to apply filters to elements without "layout", which means you should specify that element's width and height explicitly or use a css property like `zoom: 1` to force IE to do it's special secret rendering.

Comment: thanks! i cant believe i forgot to try the IE fix-all solution of `zoom:1`!

Answer (score 2):

The code here works for me in IE 8, Firefox, and Safari:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation

It's become so cliche but yes you should also consider using a library like jQuery which can do this in 1 line.

A jQuery example:  http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/fadein-fadeout-fade-out-effect-in-html-text-div-using-jquery.html